# What are some natural, non-animal sources of heme?

Tags: veganism, meat-substitutes

Recently Pat Brown introduced the Impossible Burger with the "magic" ingredient of heme, a naturally occurring bio-chemical in animals, that makes meat smell, taste and bleed like meat. What are the naturally occurring non-animal sources of heme?

Answer (score 4):

[Heme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heme) is a chemical compound most widely known because of it being a **part of hemoglobin** - the oxygen carrier in our bodies. It is, however, found in other hemoproteins such as myoglobin (muscle tissues) etc.

It is **usually found only in animals** - that is also part of the reason why the absorption rate of iron from these sources is estimated to be 7%-35% as opposed to 2%-20% absorption rate of iron from plant sources (which do not bind iron to heme). It can, however, be found and **extracted from root nodules** of some plants, notably of soy. The way folks over at **Impossible Foods** get their heme is by [fermentation of engineered yeast](https://www.pri.org/stories/2016-09-23/veggie-burger-bleeds-might-convince-some-carnivores-eat-green) - not unlike other "fake meat" companies like Quorn which use engineered and lab-grown mycoproteins.

**TL;DR:**
It is most likely grown from engineered yeast, or, alternatively, harvested from root nodules of certain plants.